# IronMQ push queue sending unknown HTTP requests

Tags: apache, iron.io, ironmq

I setup my push queue endpoint as `POST /iron`, which works fine. But I'm getting a bunch of other requests too. Are these from Iron.io? What's the point of them? They're just filling up my Apache log. My server is returning 500 errors for all of them (500 instead of 404 in development mode).

`POST /webhooks`
`POST /orders/webhook`
`POST /api/orders/webhook`

Edit: I looked into it using `multicast` and noticed only my first server was getting these weird requests. They seem to be totally unrelated to iron.io. I guess it's just coincidence they're webhook requests and I just noticed them now. Probably someone put my server as an endpoint for their webhooks. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IronMQ won't send any "unknown" requests. If your endpoint doesn't return a 200, the push queue will keep retrying the message until it either a) receives a 200, or b) fails the "max_retries" number of times.

Also per Featilion's answer, check the multicast/unicast/subscriber setup as well. If you are getting requests to those other endpoints then there's something up with your subscriber setup.

Feel free to jump into live chat if you don't figure out your answer rather quickly.

Answer (score 2):

If you added all those endpoints (subscribers) to your queue it's possible that IronMQ sends multiple requests. Check your queue's subscribers list.

```
GET /projects/{Project ID}/queues/{Queue Name}
```

If it contains multiple endpoints and its type is `multicast` - this is the reason of multiple requests on your side. In this case remove all odd subscribers (or setup new queue).

```
DELETE /projects/{Project ID}/queues/{Queue Name}/subscribers
```

In other case contact support ( :

More information at http://dev.iron.io/mq